# PHP Script freezes after Mail()

Tags: php

PHP script freezes after the `mail()` command when run through a webpage, but runs fine on SSH.

Page just keeps loading forever, nothing executes after the `mail()` command, however, the `mail()` command does work and sends an email.

What could the problem be?

Comment: we're going to have to see the code..

Comment: you have to show your code, otherwise nobody would be able to say what problem could be

Comment: Also you should add a short description of your setup to the question. What operating system? What mail setup in php? How is php integrated?

Comment: By freezes, what do you see? Error 500 or just blank page? Sounds to me like there's no response being sent back to be displayed. But yeah, let us see the code. Also have a look through error logs (/var/log/apache2 i presume).

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment, but its a bit long.

You've not provided nearly enough information here.

It has been suggested that we need to see the code - if your description is accurate then we don't, however given the quality of information supplied the predicate is very dubious. What happens when you run something like:

```
 <?php
 print "started<br />\n";
 while (ob_get_level()) ob_flush();
 flush();

 $result=mail('youruser@localhost', 'test', 'test');
 print "result=" . var_export($result, true);
 exit;
```

What do the access and error logs show for the script?

What does your MTA logs show?

What is your MTA?

What OS is this running on?

> but runs fine on SSH

Does your CLI SAPI use the same php.ini files as the web server?

If not what are the respective configurations?

Are you running the CLI as the webserver uid?

(hint - that's 8 questions you need to answer before anyone can make an informed guess as to what's happenning here)

Comment: MTA is Exim. Ran your script on 3 diff browsers - first time i ran  - prints out "started", then page loads forever - 2nd, 3rd time - page just loads - no print out - email is sent - looking thru Exim logs now ... I've never heard of CLI SAPI - how do i tell which php.ini file it uses?

Comment: Run a script containing phpinfo() or start php from the command line with -i switch

Comment: Configuration File (php.ini) Path /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File /usr/local/lib/php.ini